# Doctrine 2 lazy loading won't work

Tags: doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I'm starting with Doctrine 2 and I'm trying to make this simple case working: a Series has a title, which is a MultilingualText (encapsulates the English and French titles).

I'm loading a Series, but when I try to get its French title, the lazy loading doesn't work.

Here is the Series code:

```
    class Series {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="smallint", name="seriesId")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $seriesId;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="MultilingualText")
     * @JoinColumn(name="title", referencedColumnName="multilingualTextId")
     **/
    private $title;

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(MultilingualText $title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

Now the MultilingualText code:

```
class MultilingualText {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="smallint", name="multilingualTextId")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $multilingualTextId;

    /** @Column(type="text") */
    private $frenchText;

    /** @Column(type="text") */
    private $englishText;

    public function getFrenchText() {
        return $this->frenchText;
    }

    public function setFrenchText($frenchText) {
        $this->frenchText = $frenchText;
    }
}
```

Now the loading, which doesn't work:

```
$series = $entityManager->find('Series', 1);
echo $series->getTitle()->getFrenchText();
```

Surprisingly however, this does work:

```
$multilingualText = $entityManager->find('MultilingualText', 1);
echo $multilingualText->getFrenchText() . "<br/>";

$series = $entityManager->find('Series', 1);
echo $series->getTitle()->getFrenchText();
```

Result:

```
My French title
My French title
```

From this test, I conclude that lazy loading doesn't work in this context, but no idea why...

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Mat

Answer (score 0):

I found the thing: dev mode was set to false...
This simple line is damn important!

```
    $isDevMode = true;
```